# Describing a Matrix of Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ are $n\times n$ matrices with elements that are functions of $z\in \mathbb C$. Further, suppose that $A(z)$ is diagonal and that $$\det\left(A(z)B(z)-I_n\right)=0$$ has exactly $n$ roots, denoted by $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Let $C$ be a matrix with column $i$ given by the eigenvector of $A(z_i)B(z_i)$ with eigenvalue $1$.

Is there a more direct way to describe the matrix $C$?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a "more direct way to describe the matrix". Could you give a simplified example where you have the kind of description you're looking for? For example, what would you say about this matrix $C$ in the case that $A(z) = I$?

Comment: That is a good point, I don't even know how to describe it in this simpler case. I was hoping it could be described as the eigenvector matrix of some eigendecomposition.

Comment: You might find it helpful to note that this determinant can also be written as the determinant of the block-matrix
$$
\det(A(z) B(z) - I_n) = \det \pmatrix{A(z) & I_n\\ I_n & B(z)}
$$

Comment: Is anything known about the nature of $A(z),B(z)$? For example, are the entries of the matrices polynomials of $z$?

Comment: Yes, for the problem I have at hand that is exactly the case, i.e. entries of the matrices are polynomials of $z$.

Comment: Can you say anything else? Is there a bound on the degree of these polynomials?

Comment: Yes, polynomials in $A(z)$ have a finite degree. Not the case for $B(z)$, but I would be interested in an answer for that case also.

Comment: "Finite" isn't a very good bound; every polynomial has a finite degree by definition. If the entries of $B(z)$ don't have a finite degree, then the entries of $B$ are not polynomials.

Comment: Apologies. The elements in the diagonal of $A(z)$ are polynomials of degree 2, and I would be interested in the case in which the elements of $B(z)$ are also polynomials.

Comment: Also, $\det(A(z))\neq 0$.